# Is there a conventional meaning of $\bumpeq$ symbol in statistics?

Tags: notation, definition

I was reading a paper on Bayesian curve fitting ([Dimatteo et. al. Bayesian curve-fitting with free-knot splines, 2001](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ekass/papers/bars.pdf)) and came across the symbol $\bumpeq$. It is used a few times throughout the paper but never explicitly defined. After a few google and stackexchange searches, it appears as though the symbol is neither widely used nor conventionally defined.

Below I give an example with context from the cited paper. I apologize in advance for not defining any of the other symbols, but doing so would amount to copying over large portions of text from the paper I have linked to and would be of little use to the question.

From p1059 (equation 8):

> Incidentally, we can also see this in the likelihood ratio approximation for the normal model in equation (6) by
>
> $$\frac{p(y|k^c,\xi^c)}{p(y|k,\xi)}\bumpeq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{(y-B_{k,\xi}\hat{\beta})^T(y-B_{k,\xi}\hat{\beta})}{(y-B_{k,\xi^c}\hat{\beta^c})^T(y-B_{k,\xi^c}\hat{\beta^c})}\right)^{n/2}=exp(-\text{BIC}/2)$$

From context it seems that $\bumpeq$ represents an approximation. If this is case, then is it synonymous with  more conventional symbols for an approximation like $\approx$ or $\sim$? or is it being used to represent a particular kind of approximation for which $\approx$ or $\sim$ would be insufficient or misleading?

Comment: I'd see it as an old-fashioned version of $\approx$, which seems more common as indicating approximation. Nothing intrinsically statistical about it; it is, or used to be, quite common across mathematics. I was taught it in high school some decades ago. The tilde $\sim$ on the other hand often does mean "distributed as", which clearly does have strong statistical flavour.

Comment: If it were me, I'd take advantage of the emails at the top of the paper and ask one of them what the reason for it was. It *might* simply be an issue of journal style, but in this case I don't think that's it.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipollence_(geometry) > "Two directed line segments are **equipollent** when they have the
> same length and direction." with the equation: AB≏CD Meaning: Directed Line Segment AB **is Equipollent** with Directed Line Segment CD.

Comment: This was crosslinked in a similar question I asked on the math stack exchange. Because no satisfactory answer has been found here, or rather, it has not been `conventionally defined`, I thought I would share the conventional definition that I found, although broader to geometry.  Perhaps it could offer a clue to its intended use. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766828/what-is-the-difference-between-%E2%89%8E-and-%E2%89%8F?noredirect=1#comment3605678_1766828

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, there's no special intent beyond "approximately equal to", i.e. its meaning is not distinct from $\approx$ and has no special statistical connotation I'm aware of. (Though as I said in comments, you could always double check with the authors)

The symbol was once fairly commonly used for that purpose, though I haven't seen it much in more recent publications.

Edit: corey979 points out a recent example via a comment:  Jones M.C. & Pewsey, A. (2009) [Sinh-arcsinh distributions](https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/asp053) 
Biometrika, **96**: 4, p761–780
- middle equation in sect. 4.3

Comment: If _recent_ is 2009, then an example might be Jones & Pewsey [Sinh-arcsinh distributions](https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/asp053) - middle equation in sect. 4.3.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's pretty recent on the scale of recency I had in mind. I have made a small edit to include your valuable information.